# Run Golang project in Sublime Text 3

Tags: go, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I cannot find a suitable solution for my needs with running a Go project inside a Sublime Text 3 and seeing it's output in real-time.

If I try a build system from:

1. **GoSublime** - I can use `run`, it even runs and stops, but there is no output, which I need. It appears only when I **cancel build** - it's too late.
2. Official **Golang Build** from Go developers - I can build the project, and that's it. It allows to **run** 1 file (current) only, but I need the whole project.

   I've tried to use flags for **run** command and to add `*.go`, but then I get `*.go: no such file or directory`

How do I see the output in real-time in one of these solutions? I've tried to create my own build system with **shell_cmd** = `go run *.go`, but stopping the process with **Cancel build** is not working then. Maybe you can explain how do I stop a running Go program? My **mybuild.sublime-build** is similar to this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "GOROOT": "/path/gosrc/go",
        "GOPATH": "/path/godev"
    },
    "path": "$PATH:/path/gosrc/go/bin",
    "working_dir": "/path/godev/src/github.com/user/program",
    "cmd": "go run *.go",
    "shell": true
}
```

..I can run **Build** and see the needed output, but how do I then stop a running process?

P.S. Program is not just executing and exiting - it's a service, so I should see the output when the needed actions happens.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use GoSublime and `go build .` followed by running the app by name as a second command. Obviously this sucks in a lot of ways, but it kinda sorta works most of the time. It provides a nice fast way to check for compile errors, which is most of what I need.

Honestly, just running in a dedicated shell is nicer in every way.

AFAIK, there is no better Go build system available for Sublime Text (that isn't an endorsement, it sucks, just less than most).

Comment: What do you mean by "followed by running the app by name as a second command"? Please show a complete config/command example

Comment: There isn't anything to show, GoSublime adds a shell proxy that you can run any command in. Pressing ctrl+b (build) just brings this shell up with the last command already entered. Hence you run `go build .` to build the current package, the run the binary you just built by typing in its name. Frankly you should probably only use this shell for building and do your running elsewhere.

Comment: If you mean **Ctrl+B** and to type there **./program** - it runs, but still no output for me

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial where I was able to run Go files on build in Sublime Text 3 here: https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/streamline-your-sublime-text-and-go-workflow

If you use `Build With: Go - Run` you get outputs, but if you are running for example a net/http local host in Go you won't be able to run multiple programs and cancel build also does not work.

Here is an example of simple fmt.Println output in Sublime Text 3:

```
> Environment:
>   GOPATH=C:/Users/Christiaan/go
> Directory: C:\Users\Christiaan\Documents\02_Personal\04_Learning\09_Go\01_test
> Command: C:\Users\Christiaan\go\go1.15rc1\bin\go.exe run -v C:\Users\Christiaan\Documents\02_Personal\04_Learning\09_Go\01_test\test2.go
> Output:
command-line-arguments
gas_pedal: 22314 brake_pedal: 0 steering_wheel: 12562
> Elapsed: 3.856s
> Result: Success
```